# Internet Explorer Breaks my website?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, google-chrome-frame

My website I am working on is going great so far but when ever I try and put it in internet explorer it just breaks..
http://868rcacs.ca/test.php
I have tried using the chrome frame but it doesnt seem to work... Any help?

EDIT: I tried ie 8 and ie 7 and its almost like it it doesnt read the css at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav`, `header`, `article`... IEs < 9 don't support HTML5 tags. However, you can style them in those older IEs using for example [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Answer (score 1):

Well without code or anything we can't actually help. But here is [css support for IE6-10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this is another [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/) on IE CSS Support that might also help.

If your using css that is not supported on a particular version then you should consider removing that css OR just not support IE users.

Things that you should really think about is, how many `IE6`,`IE7`,`IE8`,`IE9`,`IE10` (**IE10 sucks less**) users will my site have and how many non-IE users will it have. If you expect about only 3-5% (more or less) of your total users use IE then it would be better to just not support IE and not sacrifice a better user experience for 95% of your users.

BUT if you really HAVE to support IE then you should consider removing the css that is breaking your site layout.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is breaking? It is working fine for me in IE v10.0.9200.16635 besides the classic image border issue for IE which you can fix easily by adding a css rule:

```
a, img {
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: I tried ie 8 and ie 7 and its almost like it it doesnt read the css at all